# image not repeating vertically in CSS

Tags: css

The top background image is not repeating or displaying full height in IE7.
It works in Firefox and Chrome.

The home-top class:

```
.home-top{
  background: url('../images/top-home-bg.gif');
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  height:180px;
}
```

In `home-top` there is a backgorund image which is not displaying behind the second separator at top.

http://dev.getchkd.com/index.php

Comment: Do you mean the flower in the frame?

Comment: A little more detail and some code, particularly showing the CSS relating to the background image would be useful here.

Comment: .home-top{background: url('../images/top-home-bg.gif');float:left;width:100%;text-align:center;height:180px;} in home-top class there is a backgorund image which is not displaying behind the second separator at top  . it is not working in IE7

Comment: Also saying it doesn't work in IE is insufficient; what version(s) of IE does it not work in?

Comment: @AshutoshMishra Please do not add details to the question as comments.  Please edit the question with additional details.

Comment: what u want really? @Sn0opy:image is full size -  http://dev.getchkd.com/images/image4.gif

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you provide and image of what you want? Looks fine for me in Opera and Chrome. Except the graphic itself, the flower looks like it's made out of 6 pictures.

Comment: @snoopy m talking about .home-top{
  background: url('../images/top-home-bg.gif');
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  height:180px;
}. this background image has problem not the nivo-slider image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a valid doctype as the very first line of your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

without this, your page is rendering in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which [causes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Quirks_Mode_Behavior) all sorts of [problems](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) -  particularly in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'position' and 'repeat' values for the image:

```
background-image:url(...);
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

You can also set this in a single 'background' declaration if you wish.

Comment: Sorry thatvdidn't help. I think @thirtydot's answer must be the right one - it's rendering in quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is because you have an static height for that class

What's the image size??

change it and try

```
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```